# side-nav is not working properly | Angular Material | Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, navigationbar

I have navigation component which made with angular material

```js
//COMPONENT TS FILE

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { LoginDialogComponent } from '../login-dialog/login-dialog.component';
import { JoinDialogComponent } from '../join-dialog/join-dialog.component';
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.scss']
})
export class NavigationComponent {
  navItems: Object = [
    { path: '/buy', text: 'Buy', active: false },
    { path: '/rent', text: 'Rent', active: false },
    { path: '/sell', text: 'Sell', active: false },
    { path: '/mortgages', text: 'Mortgages', active: false }
  ];

  isAuthorized = false;
  navExpand = false;

  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver
    .observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(map(result => result.matches));

  constructor(
    private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe(res => {
        if (this.router.url === '/buy' || this.router.url === '/rent') {
          this.navExpand = true;
        } else {
          this.navExpand = false;
        }
      });
  }

  loginDialog(): void {
    this.dialog.open(LoginDialogComponent, {});
  }

  joinDialog(): void {
    this.dialog.open(JoinDialogComponent, {});
  }
}
```

```css
//COMPONENT CSS FILE

.mat-toolbar-row,.mat-toolbar-single-row {
  height: 50px;;
 }

.sidenav-container {
  height: 100%;
}

.sidenav {
  width: 200px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.mat-toolbar.mat-primary {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidenav {
    display: none;
  }
}

.spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

mat-toolbar-row {
  max-width: 1280px;
}

mat-toolbar {
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  max-height: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  transform: translateZ(1px);
  z-index: 9999;
  background: #fff
}

.nav-expand {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.nav-header {
  position: fixed;
}

mat-chip-list {
  margin: 0 1.2vw;
}

.logo-default {
  margin-top: 51px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 101px;
  width: 100px
}

.logo-default:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.logo-default:hover {
    filter: brightness(90%);
}

mat-chip:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

mat-chip-list {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.mat-button {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

mat-chip a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.divider {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

mat-chip a,
.divider,
.mat-button,
.nav-button {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  color: #444;
  font-size: 15px;
}

a.active {
  background: #ccc !important;
}
```

```html
//COMPONENT HTML FILE

<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
 <mat-sidenav
  #drawer
  [ngClass]="{ hidden: !(isHandset$ | async) }"
  class="sidenav"
  fixedInViewport="false"
  [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
  [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
  [opened]="!(isHandset$ | async)"
 >
  <mat-toolbar>Navigation</mat-toolbar>
  <mat-nav-list>
   <a
    *ngFor="let navItem of navItems"
    routerLinkActive="active"
    mat-list-item
    routerLink="{{ navItem.path }}"
    >{{ navItem.text }}</a
   >
   <div *ngIf="!isAuthorized; else loggedIn">
    <a mat-list-item (click)="loginDialog()">Login</a>
    <a mat-list-item (click)="joinDialog()">Join</a>
   </div>
   <ng-template #loggedIn>
    <a mat-list-item href="#">Geebrox</a>
   </ng-template>
  </mat-nav-list>
 </mat-sidenav>
 <mat-sidenav-content>
  <mat-toolbar class="nav-header">
   <mat-toolbar-row [ngClass]="{ 'nav-expand': navExpand }">
    <img
     routerLink="/"
     class="logo-default"
     src="./assets/img/header/nav/nav-logo-default.jpg"
     alt="Honadon"
    />
    <mat-chip-list *ngIf="!(isHandset$ | async)">
     <a
      *ngFor="let navItem of navItems"
      routerLinkActive="active"
      mat-button
      routerLink="{{ navItem.path }}"
      >{{ navItem.text }}</a
     >
    </mat-chip-list>
    <span class="spacer"></span>
    <mat-chip-list *ngIf="!isAuthorized && !(isHandset$ | async)">
     <mat-chip class="nav-button" (click)="loginDialog()">Login</mat-chip>
     <span class="divider">or</span>
     <mat-chip class="nav-button" (click)="joinDialog()">Join</mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip-list *ngIf="isAuthorized && !(isHandset$ | async)">
     <mat-chip><a href="#">sample_user</a></mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
    <button
     type="button"
     aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
     mat-icon-button
     (click)="drawer.toggle()"
     *ngIf="(isHandset$ | async)"
    >
     <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
   </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
 </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

It works, but it has a bug on mobile landscape resolution (rotate the screen), the sidenav menu button appears and when I click this menu button I can see only backdrop of the sidenav. How can I fix this issue or must I write own navigation panel without angular material?

Images:

Side nav on mobile portrait resolution

[image]

Appears only backdrop (on mobile landscape resolution)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code hides the sidenav when the display width is 768px or greater:

```
<mat-sidenav
    ...
    class="sidenav"
    ...

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidenav {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

This code is probably taking effect when in mobile landscape mode.

Comment: Yes it is, sorry for my carelessness. Thank you for help!